# `zeroinfl` from the `pscl` and `countreg` packages give very different results. Why?

Tags: r, pscl

I am experimenting with the `mdvis` dataset from the `COUNT` package of `R` for a teaching purpose. I fitted a zero-inflated negative-binomial model using the `zeroinfl` function from the `pscl` and `countreg` packages. However, the results of `zeroinfl` from the `pscl` package and from `countreg` package differ a lot.

The models and the outputs are provided below.

**`zeroinfl` from `pscl`**:

```
mdvisit_zeroinf<-pscl::zeroinfl(numvisit ~ reform + badh + agegrp + educ + loginc | reform + badh + agegrp + educ + loginc, dist = "negbin", data = mdvis, control = zeroinfl.control(method = "BFGS", EM=F)
summary(mdvisit_zeroinf) 
Call:
pscl::zeroinfl(formula = numvisit ~ reform + badh + agegrp + educ + loginc | 
    reform + badh + agegrp + educ + loginc, data = mdvis, dist = "negbin")
Pearson residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-0.9667 -0.8037 -0.3597  0.3154  9.4878 

Count model coefficients (negbin with log link):
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) -0.30316    0.56565  -0.536   0.5920    
reform      -0.09916    0.05543  -1.789   0.0736 .  
badh         1.11555    0.07517  14.841   <2e-16 ***
agegrp2      0.11376    0.06990   1.628   0.1036    
agegrp3      0.21126    0.08620   2.451   0.0143 *  
educ2        0.07605    0.07209   1.055   0.2914    
educ3       -0.03979    0.07295  -0.545   0.5854    
loginc       0.13209    0.07499   1.761   0.0782 .  
Log(theta)   0.04747    0.05815   0.816   0.4144    

Zero-inflation model coefficients (binomial with logit link):
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept) -30.7110   772.2930  -0.040    0.968
reform       14.3274   763.7283   0.019    0.985
badh         -1.9503     3.5392  -0.551    0.582
agegrp2      10.9236   113.6292   0.096    0.923
agegrp3       9.7723   113.6558   0.086    0.931
educ2        -0.6632     1.9878  -0.334    0.739
educ3        -0.8743     1.3501  -0.648    0.517
loginc        0.5437     1.9718   0.276    0.783
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1 

Theta = 1.0486 
Number of iterations in BFGS optimization: 106 
Log-likelihood: -4557 on 17 Df`
```

**`zeroinfl` from `countreg`**:

```
mdvisit_zeroinf2<-countreg::zeroinfl(numvisit ~ reform + badh + agegrp + educ + loginc | reform + badh + agegrp + educ + loginc, dist = "negbin", data = mdvis, control = zeroinfl.control(method = "BFGS", EM=F))
summary(mdvisit_zeroinf2)
Call:
countreg::zeroinfl(formula = numvisit ~ reform + badh + agegrp + educ + loginc | 
    reform + badh + agegrp + educ + loginc, data = mdvis, dist = "negbin", 
    control = zeroinfl.control(method = "BFGS", EM = F))
Pearson residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-0.9523 -0.8057 -0.3615  0.3106  9.6300 

Count model coefficients (negbin with log link):
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) -0.44473    0.53752  -0.827  0.40803    
reform      -0.12962    0.05106  -2.538  0.01113 *  
badh         1.13558    0.07413  15.319  < 2e-16 ***
agegrp2      0.05851    0.06359   0.920  0.35756    
agegrp3      0.18678    0.07176   2.603  0.00925 ** 
educ2        0.06398    0.06621   0.966  0.33385    
educ3       -0.04825    0.07087  -0.681  0.49599    
loginc       0.15338    0.07056   2.174  0.02973 *  
Log(theta)   0.01232    0.04778   0.258  0.79652    

Zero-inflation model coefficients (binomial with logit link):
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
(Intercept) -119.137     95.259  -1.251   0.2111  
reform         4.821      2.646   1.822   0.0684 .
badh         -21.461   4614.989  -0.005   0.9963  
agegrp2        9.261     28.341   0.327   0.7438  
agegrp3        3.502     27.984   0.125   0.9004  
educ2        -19.790    203.802  -0.097   0.9226  
educ3         -7.894      4.758  -1.659   0.0971 .
loginc        13.010     10.463   1.243   0.2137  
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1 
Theta = 1.0124 
Number of iterations in BFGS optimization: 197 
Log-likelihood: -4554 on 17 Df
```

What could be the reason for such a difference? Results from `Stata` closely resemble the results of `zeroinfl` from the `pscl` package (especially, the results for the count part of the model).

I fited the models exactly similarly by specifying the same options using `zeroinfl.control()`. I also tried to search online to see if others have reported similar issues previously, and if answers are already available. I searched for answers also on `stackoverflow` and `CV`. But I couldn't get any.

Comment: The one thing that pops out is that there is clearly complete separation in the zero-inflation component (any coefficient with absolute value greater than 10 is a red flag here). Don't know whether/why that should mess up the estimation of the count component of the model, but it seems reasonable that it could.

Comment: @BenBolker I explored the data and I suspect that there may be complete separation due to the variable `loginc` which mostly contains unique values for each case. Cross-tabulation gives for each unique value of `loginc` ,  the count is either `zero` or `non-zero`.  But I wonder how the same function just from two packages end up in different results both for the count and binary parts of the model.

Comment: I email the devs when these types of issues arise. I have always received a response from devs I've contacted that answered my question. Devs are generally quite helpful on that front.

Comment: @LeroyTyrone Okay. Will try that too.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to this, I have added an answer now. Additional remark: The functions in both packages were originally written by me and `countreg` is maintained by myself, still containing my original implementation. Some years ago the `pscl` maintainer integrated a patch into `zeroinfl()` that can sometimes lead to slightly better convergence, but sometimes not (like here). Hence the results can differ a bit. But I haven't seen cases where the differences are really practically relevant (including your example). Here, they just look different but are actually not much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Source of the problem:**

The problem is that there is no zero inflation but actually less zeros than expected from a negative binomial model - espectially in some subgroups with respect to `reform` and `agegrp`.

**Symptoms:**

Due to the lack of zero inflation, the binary zero inflation part tries as hard as it can to produce predicted zero inflation probabilities that are very close to zero for certain subgroups. Notice especially the intercept in that part of the model that is extremely small with a large standard error.

Overall this looks similar to quasi-complete separation in binary regression models. The likelihood becomes very flat and it depends on the settings of the optimizer where exactly it stops (and these settings differ between `pscl` and `countreg`).

As the two components of the zero inflation model (count vs. binary part) cannot be estimated separately, problems in the estimation of one component can lead to problems/differences in the estimation of the other component as well.

**Alternative:**

The hurdle model has several advantages here: (1) It can not only deal with zero inflation but also with a lack of zeros. (2) The two components of the model can be estimated separately and hence problems cannot spill over.

**Illustration:**

Let's compare the basic negative binomial model with its zero-inflation and hurdle counterparts:

```
data("mdvis", package = "COUNT")
mdvis <- transform(mdvis,
  reform = factor(reform),
  badh = factor(badh),
  agegrp = factor(agegrp),
  educ = factor(educ)
)
library("countreg")
f <- numvisit ~ reform + badh + agegrp + educ + loginc
m <- glm.nb(f, data = mdvis)
m2 <- zeroinfl(f, dist = "negbin", data = mdvis)
m3 <- hurdle(f, dist = "negbin", data = mdvis)
```

In terms of the log-likelihood, the zero inflation model only improves very slightly on the basic model despite needing almost twice as many parameters. The hurdle model improves a bit more but also not much:

```
c(logLik(m), logLik(m2), logLik(m3))
## [1] -4560.910 -4554.146 -4550.520
```

In terms of both AIC and BIC the zero inflation model is the worst out of these three models. AIC slightly prefers the hurdle model while BIC prefers the basic model somewhat more clearly.

```
AIC(m, m2, m3)
##    df      AIC
## m   9 9139.819
## m2 17 9142.293
## m3 17 9135.040
BIC(m, m2, m3)
##    df      BIC
## m   9 9191.195
## m2 17 9239.336
## m3 17 9232.083
```

Looking at the rootogram as a diagnostic display for the basic model, we see that overall there are actually less observed zeros than expected from a negative binomial model. But by and large the basic model already fits reasonably well.

```
rootogram(m)
```

[image: rootgram of negative binomial model]

*(Note: The version of the rootogram with confidence limits is actually produced by another package under development. The version in countreg does not have these confidence limits.)*

Comment: Thank you so much. That excellently answers my question, clears my doubt, and gives me new insight into the data and methods.